# Build angular 11 with Spring boot 2.x in one single jar

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, jar, frontend-maven-plugin

I am facing  an issue bulding an angular 11 with Springboot jar.
If I runn separatelly the apps (the backend on 8080 and the ui on 4200) they work just fine, the connection and calls in between are ok and stable.

What I am trying to do is actually integrate this. I've seen plenty of examples but I don't know where and what Am I doing wrong.

Here is a picture of the Project structure:[image]

Here are the maven plugins which are installing and copying the ui build stuff into the jar.

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
            <workingDirectory>${frontendSrcDir}</workingDirectory>
            <installDirectory>${project.build.directory}</installDirectory>
            <environmentVariables>
                <CI>true</CI>
            </environmentVariables>
            <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
            <skip>${skip.ui}</skip>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>install-frontend-tools</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v14.16.0</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>6.14.13</npmVersion>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>npm-install</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <arguments>install</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>build-frontend</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <arguments>run build --prod</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>angular-build</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/static</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${frontendSrcDir}/dist/ui</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

In the jar the build files are copied under jar/BOOT-INF/classes/static.
Here is the image [image]

What Am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In @Aborgh answer,

> So put all of the compiled files from angular in a folder called "static" under resources.

That is correct, and I am just adding some more. Specifically, when you run the build command such as `npm build`, it generates **static files** such as xxx.html, xxx.js, xxx.css in the `dist` folder.

So you want to copy all the files under `dist` and paste them into your Springboot project, place them right into the `resources/static` folder.

---

Not relevant to your question, but I would recommend you put the static files somewhere separated from your Springboot backend application. Try reverse proxies such as Nginx so you can resolve requests such as https://example.com/api/xxx to your Springboot backend application and all other requests such as https://example.com/foo/xxx to your frontend Angular views.

Comment: could you please have a look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/74569409/9145082

Answer (score 2):

Spring boot automatically serves static content if you have a folder in "resources" called "static" or "public". So put all of the compiled files from angular in a folder called "static" under resources.

Doing so will make spring boot serve angular :)