# JWT Springboot app doesn't work properly when integrating with Angular 11

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

based on this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67246187/build-angular-11-with-spring-boot-2-x-in-one-single-jar) seems like I found the issue but I really don't know how to solve it.

I have the following configuration for the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter because I am working with JWT security flow like in this [page](https://bezkoder.com/angular-11-spring-boot-jwt-auth/)
The problem is on the configuration side and not the built itself.

The configuration is like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/register/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't let me access the homepage. If I do `.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()` It will work fine.
When I access http://localhost:8080 I get:

```
2021-04-26 23:09:42.517 ERROR 10160 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.a.d.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt     : Unauthorized error: Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

This comes out form the `unauthorizedHandler` but in the configuration the `.antMatchers("/").permitAll()` is supposed to let me access the index but not.

If I go for example with `.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()` It let me acess the page, but overall It will break the security flow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following, this works for me, I am able to access homepage through this configuration.

```
http.authorizeRequests().mvcMatchers("/").permitAll()
```

and one more thing don't use ant matchers, it is not as safe and custumizable as mvcMatcher

Comment: the problem was more deep than that. Just got it out. It didn't manage to access the UI resources. like .js .css files and so on. What a mess :D

Comment: @DragosRoban Nice:) glad you solved the problem:)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wish to return a page instead of a simple JSON response on the URI `GET /`.

The configuration `.antMatchers("/").permitAll()` gives the public access to the exact resource `/`, but it does not allow you to anonymously download other resources such as `/global.css`, `/foo.js` etc.

Change it to `.antMatchers("/*").permitAll()` and this gives you public access to all resources under the `/` path.