# How to host angular build files in springboot server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, same-origin-policy

I have a spring boot config file similar to following,

```
server:
  port: 8002
  servlet:
    context-path: /api/
...

spring:
  mvc:
    static-path-pattern: "/resources/**"
...
```

I have copy pasted the build files from my angular project inside `resources/resources/static`.

Don't know if this is relevant.
Here goes my `JwtFilter.java`,

```
@Component
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    final private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Autowired
    JwtFilter(JwtUtil jwtUtil) {
        this.jwtUtil = jwtUtil;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
      HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
      HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
      FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Cookie[] cookies = httpServletRequest.getCookies();
        if(cookies == null) {
            cookies = new Cookie[]{};
        }
        Cookie jwtCookie = Arrays.stream(cookies)
          .filter(cookie -> cookie.getName().equals(StringConstants.JWT_AT_COOKIE_NAME))
          .findFirst()
          .orElse(null);

        Cookie rtCookie = Arrays.stream(cookies)
          .filter(cookie -> cookie.getName().equals(StringConstants.RT_COOKIE_NAME))
          .findFirst()
          .orElse(null);

        if (rtCookie == null) {
            httpServletResponse.sendError(401, "REFRESH_TOKEN_NOT_FOUND");
            return;
        }

        String jwt = null;
        String uid = null;

        try {
            if (jwtCookie != null) {
                jwt = jwtCookie.getValue();
                uid = jwtUtil.extractSubject(jwt);
            } else {
                httpServletResponse.sendError(401, "User not authenticated!");
            }

            if (uid != null) {
                if (!jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt)) {
                    httpServletResponse.sendError(401, "EXPIRED_JWT_TOKEN_EXCEPTION");
                    return;
                }
            }
        } catch (SignatureException exception) {
            httpServletResponse.sendError(403, exception.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String path = request.getRequestURI();
        return path.equals("/api/auth") || path.equals("/api/auth/");
    }
}
```

I have tried adding those js build files to META-INF/resources, public & resources.
No go there as well.

Dir structure is:

- java/
  ...
- resources/

  - resources/

    - META-INF/

      - resources/ [contains angular build files]
    - public/      [contains angular build files]
    - resources/   [contains angular build files]
    - static/      [contains angular build files]

Now if I go to `http://localhost:8002/` then it just says
`HTTP Status 404 – Not Found`.

Comment: This: `port: 8002` configuration - this `:8000` URL?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I typed 8000 out of habit. It's 8002. now edited

Comment: Try accessing it with http://localhost:8002/api

Comment: @sham Tried it. But didnt work. I get 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project structure needs a bit more work on it.

Check out the question here.

[Build angular 11 with Spring boot 2.x in one single jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67246187/build-angular-11-with-spring-boot-2-x-in-one-single-jar/67249018#67249018)

Delete this.

```yaml
spring:
  mvc:
    static-path-pattern: "/resources/**"
```

You want to put `npm build` artifacts inside `src/main/resources/static`.

Firstly, `npm run build` and you will find the artifacts inside `dist/`.

Copy whatever from `dist/` into `src/main/resources/static/`. For example, the `dist/index.html` will be copied and pasted into `src/main/resources/static/index.html`.

### Force Springboot to Serve `index.html`

However, there is a catch here. If you do mind a hash fragment `#/foo/bar` in the url, you need to tell Springboot to serve `index.html` on 404.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class BlogApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(BlogApiApplication.class);
        app.run(args);
    }


    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {

        return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {

                ErrorPage error404Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/index.html");

                container.addErrorPages(error404Page);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

In this way, you do not need hash mode. The same thing goes with React, Vue.

[Reference](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_30051139/article/details/80074092)

Comment: I think the `Force Sprinboot to Serve 'index.html'` is specific to Sprinbboot 1. For Springboot 2 its different I THINK. If you know that as well. please.

I tried this. ```@Bean
    public ErrorPageRegistrar errorPageRegistrar() {
        return registry -> registry.addErrorPages(
              new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/index.html")
          );
    }``` 
Didn't work though.

Comment: It worked after I added filter to ignore index.html and any related js files. Also needed to comment out servlet.context-path: /api/.
Is there any way to use prefix /api but also be able to use website like normal without prefix

Comment: @Nikhil.Nixel Conventionally, the front-end artifacts are not nested into a `.jar` package. The best practice is to use a web server, such as Nginx, to serve your front-end code from a different place. If you would like to learn that, try `URL rewrite` and `reverse proxy` in Nginx.

Comment: If an Nginx server is not your choice, try not to use `servlet.context-path`. Adding `/api` ahead of your API paths would be much more organizable.

Comment: I was able to bundle everything under one single jar file, once I placed those build files [html, js, assets] in static, resources, public. And I surrendered routing controls through the error page. Added /api to all controllers manually.